# How can I position my dropdown menu to the right in mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm creating a responsive website using Bootstrap 4. In desktop, things look good. However, in mobile, my logo stays in the center and the menu stays in the left. Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/yLMWZgd).

This is what I need to achieve:
[image]

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

I am using [this code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors) according to Bootstrap's documentation.

This is my Navbar's code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg nl-navbar navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
    target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="service-main-landing.html">
        <img src="images/logo-header.svg" alt="Logo Reebit" class="col-lg-7 col-md-4 
        col-sm-7 col-7"/>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link mr-3" href="#">Contactar un profesional</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link mr-4" href="#">Registrarme</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link mr-4" href="#">Iniciar sesión</a>
        </li>
        <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 nl-btn-nav-secondary" type="button" data- 
      toggle="modal" data-target="#registrationModal" 
      id="landingRegistrationNavBtn">Publicar servicio</button>
      </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your `navbar-toggler` position with `navbar-brand`.

```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="col-lg-7 col-md-4 col-sm-7 col-7">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```

---

Additional: Seems like you misunderstood [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). `col` should be direct child of `row` like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```